# MonoDevelop on Windows

Tags: windows, monodevelop

My google-fu has failed me - can MonoDevelop be used on Windows?  Preferably without having to compile from source?

It works well on my home Ubuntu box, and while I have Visual Studio at work, it seems there might be some advantages to having MonoDevelop too.

EDIT: I'm aware of SharpDevelop; I'd prefer to have MonoDevelop if possible, just because I've started to get familiar with the interface, and I believe the SharpDevelop and MonoDevelop are not so closely related any more.

---

Woohoo! [MonoDevelop for Windows is a supported download.](http://monodevelop.com/Download)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MonoDevelop has official support for Windows since version 2.2:

> Windows Support
>
> Windows now Officially Supported
>
> Windows is now an officially supported
>   platform for running MonoDevelop. Many
>   Windows specific issues have been
>   fixed, and some add-ins such as
>   debugging and subversion support have
>   been written specifically for Windows.
>
> Windows Installer
>
> We are releasing a new Windows
>   Installer which includes almost all
>   you need to run MonoDevelop. The only
>   external dependency is gtk#, which is
>   provided in a separate installer.

You can [download the latest stable release](http://monodevelop.com/Download).

Answer (score 8):

It seems that [MonoDevelop on Windows still has a number of outstanding problems](http://mjhutchinson.com/journal/2009/02/07/monodevelop_vista64), even when built from source (and can only be built on .NET, not on Mono).  So obviously there is no installer yet either.

The answer to my question then is **No, MonoDevelop on Windows is not ready for normal use**.

I guess I'll make do with Visual Studio and SharpDevelop on windows and wait patiently (or maybe even have a look at the outstanding bugs...!)

---

UPDATE: [MonoDevelop for Windows now has a preview installer](http://foodformonkeys.blogspot.com/2009/06/monodevelop-installer-for-windows.html) which can be [downloaded here](http://monodevelop.com/Download/Windows_Preview)

Answer (score 3):

Try [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/) . MonoDevelop is built on SharpDevelop's code base.

Comment: I'd prefer to have MonoDevelop if possible, just because I've started to get familiar with the interface, and I believe the SharpDevelop and MonoDevelop are not so closely related any more.

Comment: It seems you should build it from source: http://www.monodevelop.com/MonoDevelopWin32

Answer (score 2):

There was a [recent blog](http://foodformonkeys.blogspot.com/2009/05/monodevelop-on-windows.html) entry about MonoDevelop on Windows. Now is probably the time to try it out.

**Update:** MonoDevelop have just been released for Windows and Mac. More from [Miguel's blog](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2009/Jun-04.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but not easy.  There's certainly not an installer.

This is pretty much the only guide to getting it to work:
http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/monodevelop-list/2006-September/004442.html