# MonoDevelop in windows

Tags: c#, mono

Is there a version of Monodevelop that runs on Windows? If so where can I get it?

Comment: Why would you want to? Visual Studio Express is free.

Comment: i have visual studio i just want to try mono ( i heard lot of people talk about it)

Comment: There is now a preview release of MonoDevelop for Windows.  You can read more here: http://foodformonkeys.blogspot.com/2009/06/monodevelop-installer-for-windows.html

Comment: Also this question is an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618483/monodevelop-on-windows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you can build it and run it on Windows, but I don't think there is a binary download available *yet*.  From the docs, [here](http://monodevelop.com/FAQ#Does_MonoDevelop_work_on_Windows.3f):

> Does MonoDevelop work on Windows?
>
> Yes. MonoDevelop can be built and run
>   on Mono on Windows, although it is
>   still unstable and some features may
>   not be available. We are currently
>   working on a Windows installer that
>   will be soon be available.

Comment: There is now a preview installer: http://foodformonkeys.blogspot.com/2009/06/monodevelop-installer-for-windows.html

Answer (score 7):

MonoDevelop officially supports Windows since  2.2.  You can check the [what's new in Monodevelop 2.2](http://monodevelop.com/Download/What's_new_in_MonoDevelop_2.2) or download the last [release](http://monodevelop.com/Download).

> Windows Support
>
> Windows now Officially Supported
>
> Windows is now an officially supported
>   platform for running MonoDevelop. Many
>   Windows specific issues have been
>   fixed, and some add-ins such as
>   debugging and subversion support have
>   been written specifically for Windows.
>
> Windows Installer
>
> We are releasing a new Windows
>   Installer which includes almost all
>   you need to run MonoDevelop. The only
>   external dependency is gtk#, which is
>   provided in a separate installer.

Answer (score 4):

There are no precompiled binaries, so you'd have to build from source.  Even then, there seems to be some stability issues running MonoDevelop on Windows (see [here](http://monodevelop.com/FAQ#Does_MonoDevelop_work_on_Windows.3f)).

Some alternatives would be [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/) and/or [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/product/).

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** MonoDevelop version 2.2 and higher officially supports Windows. You can get the latest version here: http://monodevelop.com/Download

---

There is currently no official release of Monodevelop for windows. After researching it a little bit, it seems that MonoDevelop was started as a port of SharpDevelop which is an open source .Net IDE for windows. Perhaps you may want to look into SharpDevelop and see if it meets your needs.

You can find out more information at the SharpDevelop website:

http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/

You can specifically target the Mono framework when writing apps in SharpDevelop (something you can't do with Visual Studio Express). I should have pointed this out in my answer above. From the website:

> SharpDevelop has the ability to
>   compile your code against previous
>   versions of Microsoft's .NET
>   Framework, Microsoft's Compact
>   Framework or Mono (an open source
>   implementation of the .NET Framework
>   sponsored by Novell) if they are
>   installed.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way now to get MonoDevelop is running [openSUSE Linux](http://www.opensuse.org) under [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/). It's really no so hard. You will get "real" linux system with Mono & MonoDevelop running on it without any issues. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently binaries available for MonoDevelop for Windows.  This is because it has not been tested and is extremely buggy.  Ie: you will probably not get more a minute or two of use before it crashes.  Hopefully with MD 2.0 now out, this is something we will soon have time to address.

Note that you do not need MonoDevelop to use Mono.  You can use the same binaries produced from Visual Studio or SharpDevelop on Mono.